# ImageBox: How can I know which part of image is displayed on the screen?

Tags: c#, events, image-processing, emgucv

I need to create a **zoom** option for my app in the following way:

In one window I will display `PictureBox` the original image without zoom, this image will be called "World Image".
In another window I will display in double size the original image in `ImageBox` (from emgu cv, `pictureBox` with pan and zoom and more options), on which you can zoom. This will be called "Goal Image".

I want that when you zoom into the "goal image" I will mark in the world picture the part that displayed in the goal image.

I want it to look like this:

The following images were done manually.....

The ["Goal Image"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/calSU.jpg)

The ["World Image"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5S8i.jpg)

Simply, I want to know every moment which part of the picture(Goal Image) is displayed on the screen,so:

1. To which events I need to register to know that the displayed image has changed?
2. How can I get the coordinates of the displayed image, remember that the image can be zoomed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you asking us to do the job for you? You need to show us what you have tried so far, or just have someone to write this for you on a freelance site

Comment: To the question "how can I know", the answer is simple: by storing it in variables and setting up communications between the two windows so they stay synced.

Comment: your keywords: scale, mouse down, mouse position, pan. i am sure you will understand what you have to do with those keywords.